# JavaFx Application is getting stuck

Tags: javafx, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting this Exception "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" in my javafx Appliaction,
it's not showing any line number.
I am printing stack trace but it's not showing any details. Generally ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException comes with index number.Here it's not showing any index Number.

Comment: Generate the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450) and include it in the question, along with the code that is throwing the exception. It sounds like somewhere you are catching exceptions and just displaying the message, instead of the complete stack trace.

Comment: In JDK-1.8.0_151 i am getting only "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".But in JDK-9.0.4 i am getting complete strack trace.Please refer following link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586536/white-screen-is-appearing-in-javafx-application-its-getting-stuck.