# White Screen is appearing in javaFx application & its getting stuck

Tags: multithreading, javafx, java-8, java-9, javacv

We are developing video streaming app using JavaFx and JavaCv,
While playing Stream into gridPane(8X8), we are occasionally facing splashing White Screen issue and it's continuous. 
    Details:-

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(Url);
                frameGrabber.setVideoOption("preset","ultrafast");
                frameGrabber.setOption("rtsp_transport","tcp");
                frameGrabber.setOption("stimeout" , "60000");
                frameGrabber.setAudioChannels(0);
                frameGrabber.setAudioCodec(0);
                try {
                   frameGrabber.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               JavaFXFrameConverter jconverter=new JavaFXFrameConverter();//converting frame to javafx Image

               while(true){
                   try {
               Frame frame = frameGrabber.grab();
                frame.clone();
                if(frame.image!=null){          
                 updateUi(im,jconverter.convert(frame));//im->ImageView
                }
            } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {

                }
            }
                   }
            }
        }).start();


      //updateui explanation

         updateUi(ImageView im,Image image){
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    im.setImage(image);//here i m updating imageview
                }
            });
           }
```

we are not getting any Exception in jdk-8,but in jdk-9 we are getting following exception.but i am not sure whether it's related to white screen problem.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out-of-bounds for length 764
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1723)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1667)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doComputeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1520)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$200(Parent.java:81)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doComputeGeomBounds(Parent.java:117)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.computeGeomBoundsImpl(ParentHelper.java:86)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.superComputeGeomBoundsImpl(RegionHelper.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.superComputeGeomBounds(RegionHelper.java:62)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doComputeGeomBounds(Region.java:3291)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$300(Region.java:149)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doComputeGeomBounds(Region.java:170)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.computeGeomBoundsImpl(RegionHelper.java:89)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.computeGeomBounds(NodeHelper.java:117)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3831)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3793)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3741)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3895)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3687)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:766)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2522)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:410)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:436)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: Exceptions like that are usually a symptom of a threading problem (i.e. somehow accessing the scene graph from the background thread). I don't see anything obvious here (but I don't know the frame grabber API you are using).

Comment: framegrabber is only for grabbing image from url.

Comment: Also: *never* squash exceptions. At the very minimum, you should log an exception if something goes wrong. And you probably should have the `try`-`catch` around the loop, instead of inside it.

Comment: You need to do updates to the UI from the javafx application thread. Use `Platform.runLater` in `updateUi` for this purpose.

Comment: i am updating imageview inside javafx application thread only.But still i am getting same problem.

Comment: @SanitKumarsingh Any Solution you find?